# Converting C statement in to Java (Array[][] != 0)

Tags: java, c, arrays, equality

I'm changing some C code into Java, but I have come across a statement syntax that I have not seen before and I don't know what it means.

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
    count[2 * SIZE + 1] += grid[i][SIZE - 1 - i] != 0;
}
```

When adding elements of two arrays, I've never seen '!= 0' come after it.  Do you know what this statement is doing?  I can't find any reference to this online.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

`grid[i][SIZE - 1 - i] != 0` is a boolean expression which (by the C standard) is evaluated to `1` if the expression is `true`, `0` otherwise.

The same thing can be written as following:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
    if ( grid[i][SIZE - 1 - i] != 0)
    {
        count[2 * SIZE + 1] += 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahhh.  I see.  I just have never seen a conditional check outside of the usual 'if statements / switch case / ternary operator.  Thank you.

Comment: Well, to be precise `!=` is no conditional check, but a boolean expression. You can use the resulting value to change the control flow based on this condition, but you can also use its raw value as a number.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike in C/C++, in Java, the result of this test is a boolean not an integer (0/1), and you cannot add a boolean so it counts for 0 for `false` or 1 for `true`.

I suggest a simple test which avoids to add 0 to `count` uselessly. So probably faster (well, constant branching could make it slower, has to be benched) & less cryptic (that's a fact), and valid in C, C++ or Java:

```
if (grid[i][SIZE - 1 - i] != 0)
{
    count[2 * SIZE + 1]++;
}
```

Comment: On a modern CPU, this version probably is *not* faster than a version that uses a ternary expression to unconditionally add either 0 or 1 on every iteration.  In fact, it stands a good chance of being slower, especially if the elements of `grid` do not adhere to a regular pattern.  `javac` and `JIT` optimizations notwithstanding, CPUs tend to do better when they don't have to deal with branch mispredictions, and not branching in the first place is a great way to achieve that.  But of course, performance is hard to predict, and should be tested where it matters.

Comment: yeah, branch prediction is to be taken into account, and every optimization needs benching on a big scale to check if it's not counter productive.

Answer (score 0):

Booleans can be implicitly converted to integers.

It is equivalent to

```
 (grid[i][SIZE - 1 - i] != 0) ? 1 : 0
```

that is, add 1 if the condition is true and zero otherwise.